# Hot to set route specific "global" styles in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

I've just bought two Vue.js themes and I'm trying to put them together (one is like a presentation theme and the other is a dashboard theme). I managed to do most of the merging except the styles part. When declaring the *.scss and *.css of both themes in main.js they end up conflicting.

I've tried go through the documentation trying everything I found, like declaring the style files with  but the components inherit the style of the parent view, so they end up looking even worse than before.

From main.js:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Presentation);
Vue.use(Dashboard);
```

From the presentation plugin:

```
import "vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css";
import "@/assets/surface/scss/material.scss";
import "@/assets/surface/main.css";
```

The Dashboard plug-in has the same imports but with different files.

What I'm trying to do is have two global styles that I can assign to the different sets of routes (the presentation and the dashboard) but if someone has a better workaround I'm open to change.

Comment: If you are using vue router you could pass in meta properties depending on the route you're on. Note: You may have to adjust your config so global css doesn't get auto-imported in your markup. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#route-meta-fields

Comment: I understad. But once the .beforeEach finds out the route uses the meta what dop you think I should do? Because if I import the style files they will be imported globally.

Comment: I guess your problem is that all css files are within your head. Depending on your build pipeline (I assume it's Vue CLI) you have to disable auto importing css files into your index.html. Afterwards you have to define the css files (depending on each route) in your meta fields. It's just a matter of configuration. This can be done pretty easy by using Nuxt. Maybe you could use that as well for your case ...?

Comment: Doing "require" instead of "import" in a "beforeEach" route (the parent that holds all subsequent children) actually fixed it. I'm not sure how correct it is to use it that way but thank you very much. I spent about 15 hours on this o_o